# Numeric palindromes from a given range and given length

Tags: c

So i wanna do this C problem where i need to read N (0<=N<=20) and M( 0<=M<=10) then print all numeric palindromes formed with numbers from {1....N} and of length M.

Input:

```
N=15
M=3
```

Output:

```
1 2 1

2 2 2

3 2 3

...

11 3 11
...
```

Things like `12 3 12` are not considered palindrome.

I tried to find compress this this palindrome to be just a number but it shows me numbers that are not supposed to be palindroms to.

Can you give me some hints on how to do this? Or if you can help me do this it would be very nice.

Comment: Won't there be huge numbers of these? Are you just trying every combination and detecting which ones work, or are you trying to construct them? You could just generate every palindromic sequence of M digits (where the digits are <= N), which is all possible sequences of length M/2 rounding up and then fill in the rest with the reverse sequence of M/2 digits rounding down, and then you can print all possible permutations of that string split so that the individual sections are <= N.

Comment: Oh, I see now M is the number of numbers, whereas I thought you meant number of digits. The simplest way to do this might be to turn your candidate list of numbers into a string without spaces between the numbers, and then you can check that the string is a palindrome or not. However I really don't like solving numeric problems like this using strings, and I still think trying to construct the palindromes is the way to go, although I appreciate there are complicated cases like `10 10 1`.

Comment: yeah, the problem is that will show palindromes that contain 0 for M>4 like 1 0 1 0 1 and the values are from 1. I really don't get what condition or how should i do it

Comment: If you're getting zeros in your output then you must be generating the zeros somehow? So that should be easy enough to fix. Can you show us the relevant parts of your code you're having trouble with?

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/Ywja9FGb) here is a pastebin of what  i have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for but to be honest the problem intrigued me so I created a rather simplistic brute-force approach to it. Hope you'll find it useful.

The logic is the following:

- Create a function that will iterate through all possible numbers(not digits) for a given position in our array of numbers.
- Make that function call itself recursively until there is one instance of it handling each position in our array of numbers.
- The instance of the function that is handling the last(rightmost) number will check each combination of numbers for being a palindrome. If one is it will be printed out.

Ah yes, to determine if a given array of numbers is a palindrome I used the simple approach to transform the array of numbers into an array of digits. So, in other words single digit numbers are transferred as is BUT double digit ones get separated into two digits and transferred as two entries. Once I trans-coded the array of numbers into an array of digits I just run a simple algorithm that starts from both ends of the digits array moving towards the middle checking each pair for differences. If no difference is found the array of digits (and consequently the array of numbers it comes from) is a palindrome.

That is basically it.

I'll supply the code below. Hope I could help. If you need any clarification or have a comment (like if I totally missed the point of the question :)) just ask!

The code:

```
#include "stdint.h"
#include "stdbool.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#define NUMBER_ARRAY_SIZE (10UL)
#define DIGIT_ARRAY_SIZE (NUMBER_ARRAY_SIZE * 2UL)

bool isPalindrome(uint32_t numbers[], uint32_t lastIndex)
{
    bool retVal = true;
    uint32_t digits[DIGIT_ARRAY_SIZE];
    int32_t digitsLastIndex = -1;

    // Turn number-array into a digit-array.
    for(uint32_t pos = 0u; pos <= lastIndex; pos++)
    {
        if(numbers[pos] < 10u)
        {
            // single digit => transfer it 1on1
            digits[++digitsLastIndex] = numbers[pos];
        }
        else
        {
            // double digits => split in two digits
            uint32_t firstDigit = numbers[pos]/10u;
            uint32_t secondDigit = numbers[pos] - (firstDigit * 10u);
            digits[++digitsLastIndex] = firstDigit;
            digits[++digitsLastIndex] = secondDigit;
        }
    }

    // This is where we check if we really have a palindrome formed by all the digits.
    uint32_t numOfSteps = (digitsLastIndex + 1u) / 2u;
    for(uint32_t i = 0u; i < numOfSteps; i++)
    {
        if(digits[i] != digits[digitsLastIndex - i])
        {
            retVal = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}

void processNumberAtGivenPosition(uint32_t positionOfNumber, uint32_t lastAllowedPosition, uint32_t largestNumberAllowed, uint32_t numbers[])
{
    // Generate and process all numbers in the actual position.
    for (uint32_t number = 1u; number <= largestNumberAllowed; number++)
    {
        // Update the number-array with the actual number(at the actual position).
        numbers[positionOfNumber] = number;

        if(positionOfNumber == lastAllowedPosition)
        {
            // We are at the last position already. Check if the current number-array is a palindrome..
            if(isPalindrome(numbers, lastAllowedPosition))
            {
                // ..if yes, then print it on the screen.
                for (uint32_t i = 0u; i <= lastAllowedPosition; i++)
                {
                    printf("%u", numbers[i]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // We still have more positions on the right. Move on to the next(->) one.
            processNumberAtGivenPosition(positionOfNumber + 1u, lastAllowedPosition, largestNumberAllowed, numbers);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t N, M;
    scanf("%u", &N);
    scanf("%u", &M);

    uint32_t numberArray[NUMBER_ARRAY_SIZE];

    processNumberAtGivenPosition(0u, M - 1u, N, numberArray);
}
```

Comment: I just read an earlier comment of yours and you said that zeros are a problem in case of M>4 like in the example 10101. To me something is not clear here. If the numbers you can use to assemble the array range from 1 to N then the number 10101 could only have been formed by making this arrangement:
10, 10, 1
and in that case M = 3

Is this correct?

Comment: Also connected to the previous question, why are the zeros in 10101 a problem? They are part of the number 10 which is an allowed number. Is there a specific ban against zeros in the palindrome or am I missing something here?

Comment: Thank you for your answear, it's not a ban against zeros i didn't explain it really good. I was talking about the case where the program that i made took 1 0 0 1 as a palindrome but the value range is from 1 to N. About your code can you explain what 0u ,1u are?

Comment: Ah I get it now! Yeah 1001 could not happen if N <= 20. 0u and 1u are just 0 and 1. The u tells the compiler that the literals are unsigned. It's just a habit I picked up by doing embedded programming. In this case it's utterly unimportant :)

Comment: Just to be sure that we are on the same page. 1001 could not happen but if (like in your example) N=15 and M=3 then 10101 can happen and that would be a valid palindrome right?

The numbers forming the set have to be between 1 and N but once we assemble the numbers into a set we stop looking at them as numbers and look at them as individual digits. Like you said for example 12 3 12 would not be a palindrome.

To sum up my point is that while the 1..N range applies to the numbers we use to assemble the set it doesn't apply to the digits of the set once we assembled it. Or is that wrong?

Comment: yeah u are right i doesn't matter if there are 0 like we can use number 10 but 0 is not a allow as a single digit. Thank you very much !